# Automatically login through external file

Tags: login

Something is wrong in this file, but I don't know what...
note: the ID that goes into `load()` is correct :-p

```
include_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');

$w = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result = $w->query("SELECT `entity_id` FROM `customer_entity_varchar` WHERE `value`= '".strip_tags($_GET['i'])."' LIMIT 1;");

if(count($result)>0){
    //
    // customer exsists login now
    //
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        try {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($row['entity_id']);
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            //nothing for now
        }
    }
    header('Location: /checkout/onepage/');
} else {
    header('Location: /checkout/onepage/');
}
```

UPDATE:
Found this as the answer but... what does it do?

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

Comment: What do you want by this code? This script has some security issues.

Comment: Ik logs a person in by validation of special attr. What is the security issue? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what do you want to do with this code, I can't figure. Maybe you need some functionality like checkout abandoned cart. You send some link to the customer email, and if customer clicks this link he should go to the checkout page with automatic authorized to own account. If you want like this, I would prefer accomplish the feature with Magento friendly way. Write some module which handling auto login, why you need external script? Follow these steps:
1. Create custom module.
2. In some controller of the module you can handle auto login.
3. You should follow the functionality "Forgot password", I mean every auto login link should have security token and it should expires after some period or after login successfully, like following:
`yourdomain.com/myroute/account/login/?id=12&token=0bd3fc89cdb44aec8961f85461a441d2`
4. Validate the token, is it valid or nor expired.
5. I give you some logic here:

```
class Your_Module_AccountController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/');
            return;
        }
        $session  = $this->_getSession();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        $customer->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        if ($this->_validateToken($customer)) {
            $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $session->renewSession();
            $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/');
            return;
        }

        $session->addError($this->__('Invalid link.'));
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '404 Not Found');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status', '404 File not found');
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer session model object
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }

    protected function _validateToken()
    {
        $result = false;
        $token  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('token');
        /*
         * here is your own secure logic to validate this token for example:
         * $email  = $customer->getEmail();
         * $result = md5($email.'SOME_SALT_STRING') == $token;
        */

        return $result;
    }
}
```